# Visual Studio EnvDTE - Open project folder in file explorer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, envdte

When you right click a project  in visual studio, there is an option "Open folder in File Explorer". How can the same be done from the automation model (EnvDTE) of visual studio? I thought I could use [Project.FullName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.project.fullname.aspx) but that didn't work for our auto generated project files that have the .vcxproj file in a different folder than the actual .cpp files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

> Project.Properties.Item("FullPath").Value

to get the correct path.

Comment: This is useful information, but my auto-generated projects don't seem to be having this property.

Comment: @chakrapanibhat: Can you check what kind of properties are available for your project?